# -bash: ./conn.sh: /usr/bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I'm getting this error while executing this script

```
-bash: ./conn.sh: /usr/bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

It's a Linux system (Ubuntu)

Comment: 1. Please [edit] your question to include `ls -l /usr/bin/bash`. 2. Please [edit] your question to identify if you created the script file on a Windows computer and then transferred it to your UNIX/Linux/Mac system. 3. Please [edit] your question to identify what type of system you are using

Comment: @roaima I just edited it... btw its a linux system

Comment: Still waiting for answers to #1 and #2 though

Comment: @roaima sorry buddy I'm not able to get you... It's a ubuntu system

Comment: What don't you get? I asked you to run `ls -l /usr/bin/bash` and put the command and its result into your question.

Comment: The most frequent cause of this is an invisible character on the shebang line: most usually a CR character. Use cat -vet ./conn.sh: a CR shows up as ^M.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant On my OpenBSD system, the actual error message would include  `^M` at the end of the interpreter if that was the case here. I can also imagine the error message being garbled instead, but it isn't.

Comment: @Kusalananda Does that on my Linux Mint too, and OP says he has Ubuntu. But it might have been omitted from the post.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I just tested on an Ubuntu system and it also  prints `^M` if it's a DOS text file, so unless they have removed it from the error, the issue seems to be a missing `/usr/bin/bash` (not available on the Ubuntu here either). They also accepted my answer, signalling that they were able to pick another pathname for the interpreter. None the less, you were totally correct in that this very well _could_ have been a CRLF issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your system does not have a `bash` interpreter at `/usr/bin/bash`, but the `conn.sh` script specifies that this is the interpreter to use in its initial `#!` line.

Modify the script's first line (the `#!` line) so that it points to the correct location where `bash` is installed.  On most Linux systems, this is `/bin/bash` (so the first line should likely be `#!/bin/bash`), but you can also check this with

```
command -v bash
```

in a terminal.